# Batch Script: Move Files to Folders Based on Modified Date

Tags: batch-file

I need to move certain files to another folder based on modified date.

I came up with the following batch script for the move.

```
    @ECHO OFF
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "FolderA=D:\IN\Set1"
    set "FolderB=D:\IN\Set2"
    set "FolderC=D:\OUT\"

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (D:\input.txt) do (
    Xcopy "!FolderB!\%%~a" "!FolderC!\" 
    Echo Copied "%%~a" to "!FolderC!"
    )

    for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in (D:\input.txt) do (
    Xcopy "!FolderA!\%%~a" "!FolderC!\" 
    Echo Copied "%%~a" to "!FolderC!"
    )
```

The input.txt contains file names as:
file1.dat,file_abcd_efgh_ijklmnop02-2014.dat
file2.dat
file3.dat

1. The destination, FolderC, should actually be set as D:\OUT\2014\P02 which is based on file_abcd_efgh_ijklmnop02-**2014**.dat --> (2014, 02).
2. While moving from FolderB to FolderC, we should check if file has modifed date within past 34 days. If so, and the file name is file_abcd_efgh_ijklmnop02-2014.dat, check if a folder D:\OUT\2014\P02 exists, else create it.
3. While moving from FolderA to FolderC, the files should be checked for modifed date within past 34 days, and should be moved to D:\OUT\2014\P02.

Thanks.

Comment: Before you go any further take a look at Robocopy.  It has 'File Selection Options'.  Robobopy /?

Comment: @user3616058 - do you have a solution?